# Proxy Error - Java Web Applications / Glassfish / MySQL / Apache

Tags: mysql, java, apache2, glassfish, aws-ec2

I have some Java Servlet Web applications running on Glassfish, on an AWS Linux server. The applications are integrated with a MySQL database, installed on the same server. Also, access management is done through Apache.

What is happening is that applications freeze and often crash, without there being any indication in the logs; neither in the Glassfish, nor MySQL nor Apache logs. The only information that appears in the browser regarding the error is:

> Proxy Erros. The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request.
> Reason: Error reading from remote server. Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at serverweb.domain.com.br Port 443

At this point the applications crash. Sometimes, I can even access it, but very slowly and soon after the application crashes again.

My server settings are:

Linux Ubuntu 18.4, AWS 2 CPUS, 8GB RAM, 20GB storage.
Glassfish is configured with -Xmx1536m and -XX:MaxPermSize=384m. The Glassfish server is restarted daily due to memory consumption. This restart is done automatically during the night so as not to affect the functioning of the applications.

Applications access the database using the Hibernate framework. These are the Hibernate settings:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement">2</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">200</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">1500</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge">1200</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">7</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">250</property>
```

Due to the fact that the cause of the problem does not appear in the logs, I have no idea what could be causing these crashes. It is worth mentioning that this problem started to appear recently and occasionally occurred every 15 days. The issue is that it is now occurring almost daily, at the end of the day.

Has anyone experienced something similar and if they have any advice on what I should investigate? I have no idea what could be causing this problem.

Comment: Additional DB information request from your AWS instance, please. 
AWS instance type?, Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: I have experience with a few systems that required DAILY restarts to survive the day.  It is nice to NOT have this DAILY requirement.  Let me know when you are ready for assistance.